# Get a range's start and end offset's relative to its parent container

Tags: javascript, textrange

Suppose I have this HTML element:

```
<div id="parent">
 Hello everyone! <a>This is my home page</a>
 <p>Bye!</p>
</div>
```

And the user selects "home" with his mouse.

I want to be able to determine how many characters into `#parent` his selection starts (and how many characters from the end of `#parent` his selection ends). This should work even if he selects an HTML tag. (And I need it to work in all browsers)

[`range.startOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.startOffset) looks promising, but it is an offset relative only to the range's immediate container, and is a character offset only if the container is a text node.

Comment: >This should work even if he selects an HTML tag<
What do you mean by this? How will someone select a HTML tag? Please explain.

Comment: If the user selects everything in `#parent`, his selection will include some HTML tags (<a> and <p>)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64618729/how-do-you-get-and-set-the-caret-position-in-a-contenteditable/64823701#64823701

Answer (score 245, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comments, my original answer (below) only returns the end of the selection or the caret position. It's fairly easy to adapt the code to return a start and an end offset; here's an example that does so:

```js
function getSelectionCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = 0;
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    var sel;
    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
            start = preCaretRange.toString().length;
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            end = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        }
    } else if ( (sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", textRange);
        start = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        end = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return { start: start, end: end };
}

function reportSelection() {
  var selOffsets = getSelectionCharacterOffsetWithin( document.getElementById("editor") );
  document.getElementById("selectionLog").innerHTML = "Selection offsets: " + selOffsets.start + ", " + selOffsets.end;
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.addEventListener("selectionchange", reportSelection, false);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", reportSelection, false);
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", reportSelection, false);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", reportSelection, false);
};
```

```css
#editor {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid green 1px;
}
```

```html
Select something in the content below:

<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">A <i>wombat</i> is a marsupial native to <b>Australia</b></div>
<div id="selectionLog"></div>
```

Here's a function that will get the character offset of the caret within the specified element; however, this is a naive implementation that will almost certainly have inconsistencies with line breaks, and makes no attempt to deal with text hidden via CSS (I suspect IE will correctly ignore such text while other browsers will not). To handle all this stuff properly would be tricky. I've now [attempted it](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule) for my [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy) library.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/TjXEG/900/

```
function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var caretOffset = 0;
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    var sel;
    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        }
    } else if ( (sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return caretOffset;
}
```

Comment: @TimDown: Having trouble getting this to work with a modal/iframe: http://jsfiddle.net/QcN4G/. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Travesty3: Yes: use the iframe's `Window` and `Document` objects instead of `window` and `document`. I've updated my answer and your example: http://jsfiddle.net/QcN4G/2/

Comment: @TimDown: Great, thanks! For my specific example (using TinyMCE), I actually found a simpler way: [`tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, newContent);`](http://jsfiddle.net/QcN4G/3/), which I found [here](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=12436#p12436). But +1 for the help!

Comment: @RafaelDiaz: Yes, and any other line breaks implied by HTML or CSS. It's not an ideal solution.

Comment: @TimDown is there any way of modifying this to getting the position via that elements html instead?
e.g. 
Html string: "<div class="c1">Hello</div>
And the cursor has sellected "el" in Hello
it would return 17

Comment: @user2330270: Not really. There are many different valid HTML representations of the same DOM so an offset within one may not be valid within another. I assume that what you want is probably the offset within the original HTML sent to the page but that's very diffifcult: the issue is that once the browser has parsed a page's HTML into DOM, that HTML is thrown away and can't be retrieved via JavaScript running in the page. In theory you could do it by re-requesting the original page and parsing the HTML by hand but that's a pretty insane thing to do.

Comment: @TimDown I'd suggest to add a `win.getSelection().rangeCount > 0` check before running `win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)`, to prevent errors as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935320/uncaught-indexsizeerror-failed-to-execute-getrangeat-on-selection-0-is-not. I've run into the problem myself, the rangeCount check fixed it

Comment: @Gregor: Fair point. I do usually add that check in my selection-related answers but obviously omitted it here. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful, the fiddle is NOT up to date. The function work perfectly tough :).

Comment: @Richard: Do you just mean that the fiddle didn't have the `rangeCount` check? I've fixed that now.

Comment: @TimDown I googled several variations of this, and your name came up in answers for every question I encountered. Quite nice code. Thanks a lot for an excellent technique.

Comment: @TimDown Do you know of a way to reverse this, creating a selection from the offsets generated here? My attempts are failing with a `Failed to execute 'setEnd' on 'Range': There is no child at offset 30.`

Comment: Omg I just hate the fact that I can only upvote once. Thanks for that piece of code! Life saver! **Edit:** Omg and it even respects elements contained inside the editable!!!

Comment: Does anyone know how to deal with linebreaks?

Comment: @k102: Dealing with line breaks is tricky and trying to deal with all possible scenarios in all browsers is next to impossible. I have given it my best shot for Rangy, as noted in the answer.

Comment: How is this answer accepted? It only returns the cursor offset, and not the start and end offsets, like the user asked.

Comment: @omerts: Fair point. Looks like an oversight by me. However, the technique only needs a little modification to get start and end offsets. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm making a new plugin like `jquery mention input`. Im stuck in the cursor position. Your answer helps me a lot. Many thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the first instance of `end = preCaretTextRange.text.length;` actually be `start = preCaretTextRange.text.length;`?

Comment: @adam0101: Yes, definitely. Thanks.

Comment: @TimDown Why do we need `element.document`? All browser supports `element.ownerDocument`

Comment: @KimchiMan: You don't any more. `element.document` was for IE 5 and 5.5.

Comment: Is there an example where with your rangy library where the caret position is provided while respecting line breaks?

Comment: How can you generalize it to return a selection (start, end) if there is such?

Comment: `Selection#getRangeAt(0)` returns the first range in the DOM if multiple ranges are supported, probably, it would be better to use `Selection.focusNode`; also why not to iterate over text nodes to count the character position?

Comment: @4esn0k: Using `focusNode` and `focusOffset` is probably an improvement. There's no need to iterate over text nodes though because the `toString()` method of a range does that for you.

Comment: @TimDown Hey I've been searching for something like this for ages. This is genus, nice work man!

Comment: @TimDown if there is an image tag in it then it is not counting it's position. Can you please fix this. http://jsfiddle.net/t7gxej62/

Comment: @AzamAlvi Not easily, no. This answer is really only for quite a limited, specific use case.

Answer (score 29):

After experimenting a few days I found a approach that looks promising. Because `selectNodeContents()` does not handle `<br>` tags correctly, I wrote a custom algorithm to determine the text length of each `node` inside a `contenteditable`. To calculate e.g. the selection start, I sum up the text lengths of all preceding nodes. That way, I can **handle (multiple) line breaks:**

```js
var editor = null;
var output = null;

const getTextSelection = function (editor) {
    const selection = window.getSelection();

    if (selection != null && selection.rangeCount > 0) {
        const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

        return {
            start: getTextLength(editor, range.startContainer, range.startOffset),
            end: getTextLength(editor, range.endContainer, range.endOffset)
        };
    } else
        return null;
}

const getTextLength = function (parent, node, offset) {
    var textLength = 0;

    if (node.nodeName == '#text')
        textLength += offset;
    else for (var i = 0; i < offset; i++)
        textLength += getNodeTextLength(node.childNodes[i]);

    if (node != parent)
        textLength += getTextLength(parent, node.parentNode, getNodeOffset(node));

    return textLength;
}

const getNodeTextLength = function (node) {
    var textLength = 0;

    if (node.nodeName == 'BR')
        textLength = 1;
    else if (node.nodeName == '#text')
        textLength = node.nodeValue.length;
    else if (node.childNodes != null)
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
            textLength += getNodeTextLength(node.childNodes[i]);

    return textLength;
}

const getNodeOffset = function (node) {
    return node == null ? -1 : 1 + getNodeOffset(node.previousSibling);
}

window.onload = function () {
    editor = document.querySelector('.editor');
    output = document.querySelector('#output');

    document.addEventListener('selectionchange', handleSelectionChange);
}

const handleSelectionChange = function () {
    if (isEditor(document.activeElement)) {
        const textSelection = getTextSelection(document.activeElement);

        if (textSelection != null) {
            const text = document.activeElement.innerText;
            const selection = text.slice(textSelection.start, textSelection.end);
            print(`Selection: [${selection}] (Start: ${textSelection.start}, End: ${textSelection.end})`);
        } else
            print('Selection is null!');
    } else
        print('Select some text above');
}

const isEditor = function (element) {
    return element != null && element.classList.contains('editor');
}

const print = function (message) {
    if (output != null)
        output.innerText = message;
    else
        console.log('output is null!');
}
```

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 16px;
}

.p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 0 2px;
}

.editor {
    border: 1px solid #0000001e;
    border-radius: 2px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

#output {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./script.js" async></script>
    <link href="./stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Caret Position</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="editor" contenteditable="true"><em>Write<br></em><br>some <br>awesome <b><em>text </em></b>here...</p>
    <p id="output">Select some text above</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had to wrap the getTextLength and getNodeTextLength in an if condition checking ````if (node != null)````. Additionally I added a check for a null ````node.parentNode```` after ````if (node != parent)````

Comment: Works perfectly thanks so much.`document.activeElement` wasn't working for some reason, so I used the single div I was working with.

Comment: Thanks for this nice work. This is the only one I found which deals correctly with BR tags.

Answer (score 28):

I know this is a year old, but this post is a top search result for a lot of questions on finding the Caret position and I found this useful.

I was trying to use Tim's excellent script above to find the new cursor position after having drag-dropped an element from one position to another in a content editable div. It worked perfectly in FF and IE, but in Chrome, the dragging action highlighted all content between the beginning and end of the drag, which resulted in the returned `caretOffset` being too large or small (by the length of the selected area).

I added a few lines to the first if statement to check if text has been selected and adjust the result accordingly. The new statement is below. Forgive me if it's inappropriate to add this here, as it's not what the OP was trying to do, but as I said, several searches on info related to Caret position led me to this post, so it's (hopefully) likely to help someone else.

Tim's first if statement with added lines(*):

```
if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var selected = range.toString().length; // *
  var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
  preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
  preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);

  caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length - selected; // *
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to highlight a word  if I already have offset values with me(I am getting from server side JSON response) and want to highlight the word based on that? I couldn't find anything on rangy library where I can simply plug in those two values (`start` character offset and `stop` character offset) and highlight the word. Please advise.

Comment: I know this is 4 year old post, but can we highlight a word in such scenario where I have range to be selected

Comment: Is there a reason you check for `selected` before subtracting it? If it's 0, then you aren't changing the `caretOffset` by subtracting 0, right?

Comment: @DonnieD'Amato Good point. I did some testing and always got selected == 0 when there was no selection (never undefined or null or anything else unexpected) so you should be safe to skip that check and always subtract selected.

Comment: @CodyCrumrine As an aside, subtracting something by `null` is equivalent to using `0` (but not sure if that's true in all Javascript engines). :)

Comment: @CodyCrumrine It's sad that `window.getSelection()` doesn't work on Safari. I see that many people have this problem but currently no solution for Safari.

Answer (score 3):

This solution works by counting length of text content of previous siblings walking back up to the parent container. It probably doesn't cover all edge cases, although it does handle nested tags of any depth, but it's a good, simple place to start from if you have a similar need.

```
  calculateTotalOffset(node, offset) {
    let total = offset
    let curNode = node

    while (curNode.id != 'parent') {
      if(curNode.previousSibling) {
        total += curNode.previousSibling.textContent.length

        curNode = curNode.previousSibling
      } else {
        curNode = curNode.parentElement
      }
    }

   return total
 }

 // after selection

let start = calculateTotalOffset(range.startContainer, range.startOffset)
let end = calculateTotalOffset(range.endContainer, range.endOffset)
```