# How to get index position in textBox using javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox, cursor-position

How do i get the index position when user click in textBox using JavaScript?
for example in my textBox have this string :

```
`this is best| of the world`.
```

it should be return 13.

Comment: You want to get the index position of `|` ?

Comment: yes '|' this is indicate my cursor position in my text box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928586/get-caret-position-in-html-input

Comment: http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea