# jQuery Virtual Keyboard - set Arrow LEFT and Arrow Right

Tags: jquery, keyboard, virtual, arrow-keys

I have spent time to create a jQuery Virtual Keyboard which it is displaying when the focus is set to Input. I did almost all buttons from keyboard to work, but I had stucked to make function for keys: `Arrow Left` and `Arrow Right`.

Please people, who knows better jQuery help me to understand how shall I do these functions for Arrow left and Arrow right. Somehow I understand that it is needed to identify the position of cursor in the input field and it is needed somehow to moove it +1 or -1.

The sample details about my virtual keyboard please take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nJTaP/5/).

---

**Solved:**
**I found the right solution.
The final working [SCRIPT is here](http://jsfiddle.net/nJTaP/10/).**

Comment: something like changing the position of the cursor?
If yes, This link can help you [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)

Comment: to move cursor left and right inside of input

Comment: or you can use [jquery Caret](http://www.plugin.jquery.hk/my-plugins/jquery-caret-plugin)

Comment: I think it more complicated than to set a cursor position. The function needs to find where is the cursor position at the moment and than to change position with with +1 or -1 character. I uderstand that Caret might help. But I do not have enough experience to understand how to make the function which act as I describe above. Many thank for your efforts!!!

Comment: That's right. And that's what you need.
You can use their code. just look how they implemented this.
btw you keyboard look nice ;]

Comment: I tried today CARET - but I can not understand how I can move cursor from current position to one character left or right... the only think i could obtain to move cursor to START or to END of INPUT...

Comment: Is it possible to create a bookmarklet or js library from tge above jsfiddle? How?

Comment: @user1788736 - I did not have time before to build a JS library. I just create keyboard on the code. If you still need, we can talk separately about my experience :)
https://pasteboard.co/H8v75Nt.png

Answer (score 1):

here an example:

```
function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
  if (input.setSelectionRange) {
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
  }
  else if (input.createTextRange) {
    var range = input.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
    range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
    range.select();
  }
}

function setCaretToPos (input, pos) {
  setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
}
```

credit to: CMS from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)

**Edit:**

```
function getCaretPos(input) {
    // Internet Explorer Caret Position (TextArea)
    if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        var bookmark = range.getBookmark();
        var caret_pos = bookmark.charCodeAt(2) - 2;
    } else {
        // Firefox Caret Position (TextArea)
        if (input.setSelectionRange)
            var caret_pos = input.selectionStart;
    }

    return caret_pos;
}
```

Credit to Pandincus from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928586/get-caret-position-in-html-input)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tmh4Q/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your post - I met it already. This example is how to set Cursor to appear in position 4... but I need a way how to identify the current position and to move cursor to other position... your example might be useful in the second part... when, I have know where the cursor is positioned and then to change from current position to position I would like...

Comment: see my update man... If my answer helped you you can accept :]
any way next time a little search on google was solving your problem in 2 minutes like i did.