# Find position at which text was editted in input field

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If I want to know when an editable field (say, an input text field or a `contenteditable` div), I know that I can use the `keyup` event.

However, I can only see what the new text is, and what the text was prior to the edit, but I would like to get some additional information about the edit.

For example, one case where this would be ambiguous would be if the input text was originally <kbd>a</kbd> and the new text was <kbd>aa</kbd>. Then:

- It could be the case that the user put the cursor before the <kbd>a</kbd>, and then typed another <kbd>a</kbd>.
- It could also be that the user put the cursor *after* the <kbd>a</kbd>, and then typed another <kbd>a</kbd>.
- It could even be that the user highlighted the <kbd>a</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (with <kbd>aa</kbd> in the clipboard).

I would like to be able to distinguish all the cases. For example, if I could get information of the form "insert `a` at position `0`" or "delete range `0-1` while inserting `aa` in its place" it would be perfect for my purposes.

Is it possible to get this kind of information?

Answer (score 0):

You could 'diff' the text before and after an edit, however, this will not allow you to distinguish between all of the cases you have mentioned. The only mechanism I can think of is to monitor the cursor (or caret) position each time a keydown event occurs, as described in this answer:

[Get caret position in HTML input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928586/get-caret-position-in-html-input)