# How do I reinitialise a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using a plugin (https://jsfiddle.net/me7on070/) that I need to reinitialise with different parameters upon certain events happening.
Can someone tell me how to do so?
I have tried simply passing a variable like so:

```
$("input#chatMessage").intlKeyboard({
    language: t,
    suggestions: "#suggestions",
    numResults: 5 // default
});
```

Where t is the variable that is changed within the calling event. However, this does not work. The original instance of the plugin remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to modify the plugin in question to bind namespaced events, so that they could all be unbound at the start correctly before rebinding with the changed parameters.

I [forked your jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnhdrLwb/1/) which shows the full code.

The guts of it was to declare the following function up the top of the plugin [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
var ns = function (event) {
    return (event || '') + '.intlKeyboard';
}
```

Then I changed all `.bind()` and `.on()` calls to use this function like so:

```
this.bind(ns("keydown"), ...
```

Then to unbind everything, I just used `.off(ns())` and `.unbind(ns())` at the beginning.

The jsFiddle code is also copied into the following snippet/demo.

```js
/*!
 * jQuery intlKeyboard Plugin v0.1
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Ashwin Purohit and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 *
 * Date: 24 Aug 2013
 */
(function($) {
  var ns = function(event) {
    return (event || '') + '.intlKeyboard';
  }

  // Cross-browser set caret position function
  // From http://stackoverflow.com/a/512542/100208
  var setCaretPosition = function(el, caretPos) {
    if (el != null) {
      if (el.createTextRange) {
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.move("character", caretPos);
        range.select();
      } else {
        if (el.selectionStart) {
          el.focus();
          el.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
        } else {
          el.focus();
        }
      }
    }
  };
  // Cross-browser get caret position function
  // From http://stackoverflow.com/a/4931963/100208
  var getInputSelection = function(el) {
    var start = 0,
      end = 0,
      normalizedValue, range, textInputRange, len, endRange;
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
      start = el.selectionStart;
      end = el.selectionEnd;
    } else {
      range = document.selection.createRange();
      if (range && range.parentElement() == el) {
        len = el.value.length;
        normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        // Create a working TextRange that lives only in the input
        textInputRange = el.createTextRange();
        textInputRange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());
        // Check if the start and end of the selection are at the very end
        // of the input, since moveStart/moveEnd doesn't return what we want
        // in those cases
        endRange = el.createTextRange();
        endRange.collapse(false);
        if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
          start = end = len;
        } else {
          start = -textInputRange.moveStart("character", -len);
          start += normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;
          if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
            end = len;
          } else {
            end = -textInputRange.moveEnd("character", -len);
            end += normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return {
      start: start,
      end: end
    };
  };
  // Usage: call this on any input or textarea:
  // $('input.french').intlKeyboard({
  //     language: 'fra',
  //     replacements: '#suggestions' // Only makes sense for IMEs
  //     numResults: 5 // Only makes sense for IMEs
  // });
  // This will listen for changes, and replace certain key sequences with
  // international versions, for people who don't want to install a keyboard.
  $.fn.intlKeyboard = function(options) {
    // Keys that don't change caret position in input, but that
    // are used in key combinations
    var silentKeys = {
      16: true
    };
    // A reversed version of http://www.selfcontained.us/2009/09/16/getting-keycode-values-in-javascript/
    var keysToCodes = {
      "backspace": 8,
      "tab": 9,
      "return": 13,
      "shift": 16,
      "ctrl": 17,
      "alt": 18,
      "pausebreak": 19,
      "capslock": 20,
      "escape": 27,
      " ": 32,
      "pageup": 33,
      "pagedown": 34,
      "end": 35,
      "home": 36,
      "left": 37,
      "up": 38,
      "right": 39,
      "down": 40,
      "+": 43,
      "printscreen": 44,
      "insert": 45,
      "delete": 46,
      "0": 48,
      "1": 49,
      "2": 50,
      "3": 51,
      "4": 52,
      "5": 53,
      "6": 54,
      "7": 55,
      "8": 56,
      "9": 57,
      ";": 59,
      "=": 61,
      "a": 65,
      "b": 66,
      "c": 67,
      "d": 68,
      "e": 69,
      "f": 70,
      "g": 71,
      "h": 72,
      "i": 73,
      "j": 74,
      "k": 75,
      "l": 76,
      "m": 77,
      "n": 78,
      "o": 79,
      "p": 80,
      "q": 81,
      "r": 82,
      "s": 83,
      "t": 84,
      "u": 85,
      "v": 86,
      "w": 87,
      "x": 88,
      "y": 89,
      "z": 90,
      // Numpad codes -- TODO keys that, depending on if hit from numpad
      // or keyboard, can have different codes, like: "0": [48, 96]
      //"0":96, "1":97, "2":98, "3":99, "4":100, "5":101, "6":102, "7":103, "8":104, "9":105,
      "*": 106,
      "+": 107,
      "-": 109,
      ".": 110,
      "/": 111,
      "f1": 112,
      "f2": 113,
      "f3": 114,
      "f4": 115,
      "f5": 116,
      "f6": 117,
      "f7": 118,
      "f8": 119,
      "f9": 120,
      "f10": 121,
      "f11": 122,
      "f12": 123,
      "numlock": 144,
      "scrolllock": 145,
      ";": 186,
      "=": 187,
      ",": 188,
      "-": 189,
      ".": 190,
      "/": 191,
      "`": 192,
      "[": 219,
      "\\": 220,
      "]": 221,
      "'": 222
    };
    var stack = [];
    var self = this;
    // Ideographic languages that we'd prefer to use Google suggest for.
    var languageToGoogleITC = {
      zh: "zh-t-i0-pinyin",
      hi: "hi-t-i0-und"
    };
    self.unbind(ns());
    // We define most Latin keyboard mappings ourselves.
    var langReplacements = {
      fra: [ // French | Français
        // C cedille
        [
          [",", "c"], "ç"
        ],
        [
          [",", "shift", "c"], "Ç"
        ],
        // Accent grave
        [
          ["`", "a"], "à"
        ],
        [
          ["`", "e"], "è"
        ],
        [
          ["`", "u"], "ù"
        ],
        [
          ["`", "shift", "a"], "À"
        ],
        [
          ["`", "shift", "e"], "È"
        ],
        [
          ["`", "shift", "u"], "Ù"
        ],
        // Accent aigu
        [
          ["'", "e"], "é"
        ],
        [
          ["'", "shift", "e"], "É"
        ],
        // But, differentiate between C'est and Céline
        // by allowing a user to put a space after the ' to not accent
        [
          ["'", " ", "e"], "'e"
        ],
        [
          ["'", " ", "shift", "e"], "'E"
        ],
        // Circonflexe (^ = [Shift] + 6)
        [
          ["shift", "6", "a"], "â"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "6", "e"], "ê"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "6", "i"], "î"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "6", "o"], "ô"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "6", "shift", "a"], "Â"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "6", "shift", "e"], "Ê"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "6", "shift", "i"], "Î"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "6", "shift", "o"], "Ô"
        ],
        // Le tréma
        [
          ["shift", "'", "a"], "ä"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "e"], "ë"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "i"], "ï"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "o"], "ö"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "u"], "ü"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "shift", "a"], "Ä"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "shift", "e"], "Ë"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "shift", "i"], "Ï"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "shift", "o"], "Ö"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "shift", "u"], "Ü"
        ]
      ],
      es: [ // Spanish | Español
        // El acento
        [
          ["'", "a"], "á"
        ],
        [
          ["'", "e"], "é"
        ],
        [
          ["'", "i"], "í"
        ],
        [
          ["'", "o"], "ó"
        ],
        [
          ["'", "u"], "ú"
        ],
        [
          ["'", "shift", "a"], "Á"
        ],
        [
          ["'", "shift", "e"], "É"
        ],
        [
          ["'", "shift", "i"], "Í"
        ],
        [
          ["'", "shift", "o"], "Ó"
        ],
        [
          ["'", "shift", "u"], "Ú"
        ],
        // La crema o diéresis
        [
          ["shift", "'", "u"], "ü"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "shift", "u"], "Ü"
        ],
        // La ñ
        [
          ["shift", "`", "n"], "ñ"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "`", "shift", "n"], "Ñ"
        ],
        // Signos de interrogación y exclamación invertidos
        // Handles [Shift]-[?]-[?], and [Shift]-[?], [Shift]-[?]
        [
          ["shift", "/", "/"], "¿"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "/", "shift", "/"], "¿"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "1", "1"], "¡"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "1", "shift", "1"], "¡"
        ],
      ],
      deu: [ // German | Deutsch
        // Umlaut
        [
          ["shift", "'", "a"], "ä"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "o"], "ö"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "u"], "ü"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "shift", "a"], "Ä"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "shift", "o"], "Ö"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "shift", "u"], "Ü"
        ],
        // Eszett
        [
          [",", "s"], "ß"
        ],
      ],
      tur: [ // Turkish | Türkçe
        // Yumuşak ge
        [
          [",", "g"], "ğ"
        ],
        [
          [",", "shift", "g"], "Ğ"
        ],
        // ı
        [
          [".", "i"], "ı"
        ],
        [
          [".", "shift", "i"], "I"
        ],
        // Capital i becomes İ
        [
          ["shift", "i"], "İ"
        ],
        // â, î, û
        [
          ["shift", "6", "a"], "â"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "6", "i"], "î"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "6", "u"], "û"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "6", "shift", "a"], "Â"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "6", "shift", "i"], "Î"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "6", "shift", "u"], "Û"
        ],
        // çe
        [
          [",", "c"], "ç"
        ],
        [
          [",", "shift", "c"], "Ç"
        ],
        // şe
        [
          [",", "s"], "ş"
        ],
        [
          [",", "shift", "s"], "Ş"
        ],
        // ö, ü
        [
          ["shift", "'", "o"], "ö"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "u"], "ü"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "shift", "o"], "Ö"
        ],
        [
          ["shift", "'", "shift", "u"], "Ü"
        ],
      ],
      en: []
    };
    // Builds a reverse trie for key combinations, keyed on keyCode,
    // from the passed human-readable array of arrays.
    // If the combo "," (188) then "c" (67), should be replaced with ç,
    // then the trie would look like: {67: {188: {r: ç}}}
    var reverseTrieForLang = function(language) {
      var tree = {};
      var combos = langReplacements[language];
      for (var i = 0; i < combos.length; i += 1) {
        var node = tree;
        var keys = combos[i][0];
        var replacement = combos[i][1];
        for (var j = keys.length - 1; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
          var key = keys[j];
          var code = keysToCodes[key];
          if (!node.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
            node[code] = {};
          }
          node = node[code];
          if (j == 0) {
            node.r = replacement;
          }
        }
      }
      return tree;
    };
    // If this language is Pinyin, the IME is completely different.
    if (languageToGoogleITC.hasOwnProperty(options.language)) {
      // Default number of results.
      options = $.extend({
        numResults: 5
      }, options);
      var strokeBuffer = [];
      var replacementDiv = $(options.suggestions);
      var replacementUl = replacementDiv.find(".suggestions").unbind(ns());
      var replacementTyped = replacementDiv.find(".typed");
      var replacements = [];
      var mouseOnReplacement = null;
      // When a user selects a replacement. We're guaranteed that
      // index is valid for a replacement.
      var selectReplacement = function(index) {
        var decodedReplacement = decodeURIComponent(replacements[index]);
        var caret = getInputSelection(self[0]);
        var pos = caret.end;
        var text = self.val();
        // Insert the chosen suggestion at the current position.
        var replacementText = text.substr(0, pos) + decodedReplacement + text.substr(pos);
        self.val(replacementText);
        // When you replace text, the cursor auto-jumps to the end.
        // If you were in the middle of a string, that's annoying.
        // This puts the cursor back to the character you were editing.
        setCaretPosition(self[0], pos + decodedReplacement.length);
        clearSelection();
      };
      // Hide and clear the replacement divs and suggestions.
      var clearSelection = function() {
        mouseOnReplacement = null;
        strokeBuffer.length = 0;
        replacements = [];
        replacementUl.empty();
        replacementTyped.empty();

        //replacementDiv.hide();
      };
      // Sends a request to Google to get IME suggestions
      var getReplacements = function() {
        // Show or hide the replacement div (in case called backspace)
        if (strokeBuffer.length > 0) {
          replacementDiv.show();
        } else {
          clearSelection();
          return;
        }
        var encodedText = encodeURIComponent(strokeBuffer.join(""));
        replacementTyped.html(encodedText + ":");
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "https://inputtools.google.com/request",
          cache: false,
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            text: encodedText,
            itc: languageToGoogleITC[options.language],
            num: options.numResults,
            // Google sets these values in its own AJAX calls, but they're
            // cryptic and undocumented, so I'm passing them along.
            cp: 0,
            cs: 1,
            // Input and output encoding
            ie: "utf-8",
            oe: "utf-8",
            // Doesn't seem to matter what this is.
            app: "test"
          }
        }).done(function(result) {
          // The Google JSON result is terribly nested.
          replacements = result[1][0][1];
          var listElements = "";
          // Ordered lists don't retain numbering when making the
          // list horizontal with li{display:inline}
          for (var i = 0; i < replacements.length; i += 1) {
            listElements += "<li><span class='number'>" + (i + 1) + ".</span> " + replacements[i] + "</li>";
          }
          replacementUl.html(listElements);
        });
      };
      // On delete/backspace, drop the last char from strokeBuffer,
      // and update replacements
      this.bind(ns("keydown"), function(e) {
        if (e.which === 8 || e.which === 46) {
          if (strokeBuffer.length !== 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            strokeBuffer.pop();
            getReplacements();
          }
        }
      });
      // Keypress on input gets more Google Input Tools suggestions
      this.bind(ns("keypress"), function(e) {
        var charCode = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
        var index = parseInt(charCode, 10) - 1;
        // Hit a number from 1 to replacements.length
        if (!isNaN(index)) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (index >= 0 && index < replacements.length) {
            selectReplacement(index);
          }
          return;
        }
        // Hit [Space] or [Enter] -- just pick the first replacement.
        if (charCode === "" || charCode === " ") {
          if (strokeBuffer.length !== 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            selectReplacement(0);
          }
          return;
        }
        // Hit any a-z character. Don't show the
        // character in the input.
        if (charCode >= "a" && charCode <= "z") {
          e.preventDefault();
          strokeBuffer.push(charCode);
          getReplacements();
        }
      });
      // When a user clicks a replacement with the mouse
      replacementUl.on(ns("click"), "li", function(e) {
        selectReplacement($(e.target).index());
      });
      // If the user focuses out of the input element, kill
      // the suggestion box. But if they clicked on a suggestion,
      // which also triggers an input.focusout event, set
      // set the replacement and re-focus the input.
      this.bind(ns("focusout"), function() {
        if (mouseOnReplacement !== null) {
          selectReplacement(mouseOnReplacement);
          $(this).focus();
        } else {
          clearSelection();
        }
      });
      replacementUl.on(ns("mouseover"), "li", function(e) {
        var index = $(e.target).index();
        mouseOnReplacement = index;
      });
      // Make it chainable.
      return this;
    }
    // If the language is Latin-extended, we can use keystroke replacement
    var reverseTrie = reverseTrieForLang(options.language);
    this.bind(ns("keydown"), function(e) {
      var text = self.val();
      var code;
      // The trie of replacements for this language.
      var node = reverseTrie;
      // The current caret start and end position.
      var caret = getInputSelection(this);
      var replacement = null;
      // Number of keystrokes to 'erase' when replacing.
      var sequenceLength = 0;
      // On every keydown, add the keycode to the stack.
      stack.push(e.which);
      for (var i = stack.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        code = stack[i];
        // Don't count silent keys like [Shift] in sequence length.
        if (!silentKeys.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
          sequenceLength += 1;
        }
        node = node[code];
        // Couldn't "recurse" because the sequence trail ends here.
        if (node === undefined) {
          break;
        }
        // Found a character replacement.
        // Peek one more character, and if the sequence continues,
        // don't use the replacement yet.
        if (i > 0 && node.hasOwnProperty(stack[i - 1])) {
          continue;
        }
        if (node.hasOwnProperty("r")) {
          replacement = node.r;
          break;
        }
      }
      // Found a replacement sequence.
      // Use it to replace the (sequenceLength) chars before current caret position
      if (replacement !== null) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // TODO: Use a stack of length [max combo length for language];
        // this one grows ad infinitum (er, ad successus), before clearing.
        stack.length = 0;
        var pos = caret.end;
        var replacementText = text.substr(0, pos - sequenceLength + 1) + replacement + text.substr(pos);
        self.val(replacementText);
        // When you replace text, the cursor auto-jumps to the end.
        // If you were in the middle of a string, that's annoying.
        // This puts the cursor back to the character you were editing.
        setCaretPosition(this, pos);
      }
    });
    // Make it chainable
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  var lang;

  function setLanguage(t) {
    lang = t;
    $("input#chatMessage").intlKeyboard({
      language: t,
      suggestions: "#suggestions",
      numResults: 5 // default
    });
  }
  $('#change').click(function() {
    setLanguage(lang === 'es' ? 'en' : 'es');
    $('#change').text($('#change').text().replace(/(English|Spanish)/g, lang === 'es' ? 'English' : 'Spanish'));
    return false;
  });

  setLanguage('en');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="chatMessage"></input>
<ul id="suggestions"></ul>
<button id="change">Change to Spanish</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that your code actually initializes the plugin on the #chatmessage element.

To reinitialize, you can call the code to execute on an event. In this case I am getting it to reinitialize when the user clicks the #someElementID element. You can set it to any element or any type of event you want.

```
$('#someElementID').off('click').on('click', function(){

    $("input#chatMessage").intlKeyboard({
        language: t,
        suggestions: "#suggestions",
        numResults: 5 // default
    });
}
```

You may also need to remove the current plugin from the page in which case you can use something like

```
$("input#chatMessage").html("");
```

before calling

```
$("input#chatMessage").intlKeyboard( ....
```

to remove everything that is inside the chatMessage element.

Comment: Warning: If you are going to use `off` with `on` you should add a custom namespace to the event name, e.g. `click.myname`, else you will remove all `click` events from that element (regardless of what other plugins may potentially be using it). You will note the OPs source uses an `ns()` function to append such a prefix.