# How to get cursor coordinates in a text- area / input

Tags: javascript

Let's assume there is a text-area (or a simple input of type text) and the user types something.
How can I get the `x / y` coordinates of the cursor to position, as example, a `div` direct above the cursor.

Comment: You can use `selectionStart`, like answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928586/get-caret-position-in-html-input For textAreas, you can get the coordinated by counting the caracters (for example).

Comment: Try window.getSelection

Comment: try to use event.target inside the key down event for the textbox