# How to find the selection text beginning and end positions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection, getselection

I am trying to find the textual start and end of the selection.  So, in the following text, if I selected "world! What a fine" from within "Hello, world! What a fine day it is!", I should get 7 as the start coordinate, and 24 as the end coordinate assuming a zero based index.

How is this achievable?

EDIT:
I am looking to find the selection of text that is not inside any `<input>` or `<textarea>` elements.

EDIT:
Decided the solution to use disabled `<textarea>s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this:

```
/* Returns 3 strings, the part before the selection, the part after the selection and the selected part */
function getSelected()
{
  var u     = editor.val();
  var start = editor.get(0).selectionStart;
  var end   = editor.get(0).selectionEnd;

  return [u.substring(0, start), u.substring(end), u.substring(start, end)];
}
```

where editor is `$("#editor")` or whatever ID your textarea / input field may have.

Usage:

```
var select = getSelected()
editor.val(select[0] + '<h1>'+ select[2] + '</h1>' + select[1]);
```

Will wrap selected text in H1. If nothing is selected it will just add empty H1, but you can add checks and functionality to your liking.

** Not tested in all browsers, works in Chrome though **

Comment: Did you see my edit that I want this to work in DIVs and Ps? I edited it like 5 minutes before your answer so you might not have seen it.  This works fine in TEXTAREA, but start and end are `undefined` when applied to a P tag.

Comment: It seems as if this would be the correct solution if I were to switch from using <div>s to disabled <textarea>s. So, that is what I should do!

Comment: ah glad I could still help out :)

Comment: This does not work in IE below version 9, because `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are not supported: http://help.dottoro.com/ljtfkhio.php

Answer (score 2):

This is possible but slightly complicated with `contenteditable` HTML content (as opposed to text within an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element). Here's a simple cross-browser implementation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812022/96100

Answer (score 0):

But I know a jQuery plugin that aims your problem and much more - https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection

Comment: Does this only apply to input elements? I'm looking for text inside of `<p>` and `<div>` tags