# Get word starting with special characters at caret in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I have a `contenteditable div`, and I need to know the word at the current caret position. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11248187/1469954), but the problem is, it doesn't recognize special characters like `@` and `~`. So if a word starts with `~`, like `~fool`, I am getting `fool`, whereas I expected `~fool`. So I tried to modify the solution by taking into account that if after moving the selection back, the character encountered is not a space, I would continue moving backwards until a space is encountered. That would make the start of the selection. Similarly then I would keep moving forward until I find a space, and that would mark the end of selection. Then the selection would give me the word. To get the caret position, I used [this solution](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/703618/How-to-get-text-from-contenteditable-div-from-begi). Combined, my code now looks like this:

```
function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
  var caretPos = 0,
    sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
        caretPos = range.endOffset;
      }
    }
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
      var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
      editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
      var tempRange = range.duplicate();
      tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
      tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
      caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
    }
  }
  return caretPos;
}

function getCurrentWord() {
    var sel, word = "";
    if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
        var selectedRange = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        sel.collapseToStart();
        sel.modify("move", "backward", "word");

        while (sel.toString() != " " && getCaretPosition($("#editor").get(0)) != 0) {
            sel.modify("move", "backward", "character");
            (sel = window.getSelection()).modify;
        }
        sel.modify("move", "forward", "character");      
        sel.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
        word = sel.toString();

        // Restore selection
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(selectedRange);
    } else if ((sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var range = sel.createRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.expand("word");
        word = range.text;
    }
    return word;
}

$(function () {

    $(document).on('keyup keydown paste cut mouseup',"#editor", function () {
        var word = getCurrentWord();
        console.log(word);
    });
});
```

However this is not working at all. That is problem no. 1. Problem 2 is, even if there is an image in the pic and user clicks on the pic, the handler keeps returning the last word before the image, whereas I am expecting a blank string. Can anyone help me fix these two issues?

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but it sounds like between the 2 answers you have everything you need to put together a working solution for your needs. You don't have to mark either answer right, just think you have sufficient solutions to get something working for yourself :P

Comment: I am also trying stuff by myself, I am not sitting lazily for a working solution from somebody else.

Comment: My apologies, I hadnt intended to imply you were lazy. Just meant that between the two answers I think an answer is lurking.

Comment: No no, it is okay, I just said that I am also trying many things, without much luck.. :)

Answer (score 6):

I modified the `getCurrentWord()` function to use basic String methods to get the word from the caret position. The function accepts the element and position and returns the word at that position.

Below is the updated function.

```
function getCurrentWord(el, position) {
    // Get content of div
    var content = el.textContent;

    // Check if clicked at the end of word
    position = content[position] === ' ' ? position - 1 : position;

    // Get the start and end index
    var startPosition = content.lastIndexOf(' ', position);
    var endPosition = content.indexOf(' ', position);

    // Special cases
    startPosition = startPosition === content.length ? 0 : startPosition;
    endPosition = endPosition === -1 ? content.length : endPosition;

    return content.substring(startPosition + 1, endPosition);
}
```

The function first gets the content of the element. Next, it checks if the user has clicked at the end of a word, if yes, then subtract one from the position so that the `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` will work correctly on space.

For start and end positions, there are two special cases which need to be handled. First, click on the last element. For this, the `startPosition` will be `-1` since there could be no space after the last word.

Second, when clicking on the first word, the `endPosition` will be `-1` because there could be no space before the first word.

These two conditions will work even if there is space before first character and space after the last character.

`indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` are used to find the space before and after word and using those indexes `substring` will give the word at that position.

Here's [**live demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/k2xLjok3/) to test.

```js
$(function() {
  function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
    var caretPos = 0,
      sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
      sel = window.getSelection();
      if (sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
          caretPos = range.endOffset;
        }
      }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
      range = document.selection.createRange();
      if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
        var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
        editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
        var tempRange = range.duplicate();
        tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
        tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
        caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
      }
    }
    return caretPos;
  }

  function getCurrentWord(el, position) {
    var word = '';

    // Get content of div
    var content = el.textContent;

    // Check if clicked at the end of word
    position = content[position] === ' ' ? position - 1 : position;

    // Get the start and end index
    var startPosition = content.lastIndexOf(' ', position);
    startPosition = startPosition === content.length ? 0 : startPosition;
    var endPosition = content.indexOf(' ', position);
    endPosition = endPosition === -1 ? content.length : endPosition;

    return content.substring(startPosition + 1, endPosition);
  }


  $('#editor').on('keyup keydown paste cut mouseup', function() {
    var caretPosition = getCaretPosition(this);
    var word = getCurrentWord(this, caretPosition);
    console.log(word);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor" contenteditable>



  Lorem !p$um dolor $!t @met, con$ectetur @d!p!$!c!ng el!t, $ed do e!u$mod tempor !nc!d!dunt ut l@bore et dolore m@gn@ @l!qu@. Ut en!m @d m!n!m ven!@m, qu!$ no$trud exerc!t@t!on ull@mco l@bor!$ n!$! ut @l!qu!p ex e@ commodo con$equ@t. Du!$ @ute !rure dolor
  !n reprehender!t !n volupt@te vel!t e$$e c!llum dolore eu fug!@t null@ p@r!@tur.
</div>
```

Comment: Still tons of errors. For example, in the example content you gave in your fiddle, if you click on the third word - dolor, and do a `CTRL-B` to make it bold, then again click on it, it starts giving wrong words. If you double tap a word to select it, instead of that word being logged, wrong words are being logged.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty barebones example. There's a div with example text:

```
<div contenteditable onclick="getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(this)">some ~test content</div>
```

Here's the script. When we click on the div, wherever the cursor lands we get the current position and spit out the word we're in. This word can include special characters and is only space delineated.

```
function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var caretOffset = 0;
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    var sel;
    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        }
    } else if ( (sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
  console.log('caretOffset', caretOffset);
  word = getWordAtPosition(caretOffset, element);
  console.log('word', word);
    return caretOffset;
}

function getWordAtPosition(position, element) {
  var total_text = element.innerHTML;
  var current_word = "";
  var i = 0;
  var word_found = false;
  while(i < total_text.length) {
    if(total_text[i] != ' ')
      current_word += total_text[i];
    else if(word_found)
      return current_word;
    else
      current_word = "";
    if(i == position)
      word_found = true;
    i++;
  }
  return current_word;
}
```

Heres an example of it working:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWdyLV

Comment: Hmm. Almost works. Except, in the code you provided, if I click at the end of the word, i.e. now the cursor is blinking at the end of the word `~test`, the word shown is `content`, which is the next word separated by a space. And secondly, if I click at the beginning of a word so that the cursor is blinking just before the first character of the word, for the word `~test`, it return `~test`, for other words like `hello` not starting with `~`, it returns `&nbsp;`

Comment: Not to mention, if you make the `~test` word bold, the word returned is `<b>~test</b>` instead of `~test`, and clicks on the subsequent `content` word still yield `<b>~test</b>`.

Comment: First thought: is selecting `<b>~test</b>` undesirable? I think the simplest thing to do would be to write out a specific list of special characters you want to indicate word separation and go from there.

Comment: That is one of the many problems here you see. Just insert a new line and click on words on either side of the newline and see what happens.