# JavaScript - Get HTML of current line in contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got my *contentEditable* `div`:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" style="font-family: Arial;">
    <b>Lorem ipsum</b> dolor sit amet, <u>consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Morbi sagittis</u> <s>mauris porta arcu auctor, vel aliquam ligula ornare.</s> 
    Sed at <span id="someId">semper neque, et dapibus metus. 
    Maecenas dignissim est non nunc feugiat</span> 
    sollicitudin. Morbi consequat euismod consectetur. Mauris orci 
    risus, <b>porta quis erat ac, malesuada</b> fringilla odio.
</div>
    
<button>Get current line HTML</button>
```

And I want to create a button which gives me HTML code from the current line. For example:
When my caret is on the second line I want to get:

```
amet, <u>consectetur</u>
```

or on seventh line:

```
<span id="someId">dapibus metus. Maecenas</span>
```

I tried to do that using [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy), but that didn't work. How can I do that using JavaScript and/or JQuery?
Thanks for help.

Comment: That would be hard to do without some changes; in the rendered output all of those lines are one line.

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31985040/6568620

Comment: So clicking on 5th line should output vel `aliquam ligula ornare.</s>`? (won't have time to work on this before tomorrow, but there might be some ways to do it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will not code you the full finished code but here are good help that will get you the result.

First you need to get a method for figuring out lines. I suggest looking at the answer in this stackoverflow: [How to select nth line of text (CSS/JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966441/how-to-select-nth-line-of-text-css-js)
From that you can get line number for a specific word.

What word your caret is on you can get from this information: [How can I get the word that the caret is upon inside a contenteditable div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247737/how-can-i-get-the-word-that-the-caret-is-upon-inside-a-contenteditable-div)

Combining the line number functionality with current caret word you will be able to return a full row where your caret is.

Answer (score 8):

This solution is based on the example proposed by Mozilla in [`Selection.modify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Selection/modify#Example), but using `lineboundary` granularity and playing with `move` and `extend` alter parameters.

To preserve caret position, the range of the selection is stored/restored.

Play with the `width` of the content, edit the snippet and check it out.

You got your HTML.

```js
function getSelectionHtml() {
  var selection = window.document.selection,
    range, oldBrowser = true;

  if (!selection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    oldBrowser = false;
  } else
    range = document.selection.createRange();

  selection.modify("move", "backward", "lineboundary");
  selection.modify("extend", "forward", "lineboundary");

  if (oldBrowser) {
    var html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    range.select();
    return html;
  }

  var html = document.createElement("div");

  for (var i = 0, len = selection.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
    html.appendChild(selection.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
  }

  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  return html.innerHTML;
}

document.getElementById("content").onmouseup = function(e) {
  var html = getSelectionHtml();
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = html;
  document.getElementById("code").textContent = html;
};
```

```css
h4,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

#code {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
}

#content {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
<div id="text"></div>

<div contenteditable="true" id="content" spellcheck="false" style="font-family: Arial;">
  <b>Lorem ipsum</b> dolor sit amet, <u>consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Morbi sagittis</u> <s>mauris porta arcu auctor, vel aliquam ligula ornare.</s> Sed at <span id="someId">semper neque, et dapibus metus. 
    Maecenas dignissim est non nunc feugiat</span> sollicitudin. Morbi consequat euismod consectetur. Mauris orci risus, <b>porta quis erat ac, malesuada</b> fringilla odio.
</div>
```

Comment: I think its close but if I understand correctly he wants the html tags as well. Also I don't think changing caret position is good if it is editable content and caret changes to line instead if he wants to keep editing. maybe store the caret pos and then return it after click or so would solve that.

Comment: Not sure what OP really is after, but if I got it right, clicking on the third line should not show `</a>` since this is part of the 4th line. (but once again I'm not sure about OP's requirements). And I think you miss the `<h4>` too.

Comment: @Kaiido selection range `cloneContents` returns DOM nodes, thus creating valid html, which is a great thing. Let's see what the OP really needs whether to include the ' <h4>'  or not.

Comment: Actually @Kaiido, if you see the OP examples he is including the missing parts of the html that makes valid markup ;)