# Get selection start in content editable div

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, selection, contenteditable

**READ BEFORE MARKING DUPLICATE:**

1. The contenteditable div will **not have child elements**
2. I do not want a cross-browser solution, **only Chrome support** required
3. Only **vanilla JS**, no libraries.

I have looked up almost all the posts on Stackoverflow (would be quite surprising for me if this post turns out to be a duplicate), and found this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cpatik/3QAeC/

Its `getSelectionBegin` code was:

```
function getSelectionBegin(element) {
    var caretOffset = 0;
    if (w3) {
    }
    else if (ie) {
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", textRange);
        caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return caretOffset;
}
```

Notice the `w3` part (which I require) is blank. Seemed to me like there's no method for getting selectionStart, but I assume someone might have developed a hack to get round this.

So the question:

> How do I ***get* the `selection start`** in a content editable div ?

**UPDATE**:

As it turns out, there was a solution, but apparently missed by me due to [the bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115860/set-caret-position-at-a-specific-position-in-contenteditable-div#comment37217865_24117242) I had before

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4812022/96100

Comment: @TimDown Interesting! I must have tried it, but before finding the `element.focus` [bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115860/set-caret-position-at-a-specific-position-in-contenteditable-div#comment37217865_24117242) I had. Feel free to close this as a duplicate :) I voted myself!