# Select last word or specific range of Contenteditable

Tags: javascript, selection, contenteditable

I've been trying to select only the last chars of a `ContentEditable` Element

I've used an example from Mozilla on http://jsfiddle.net/mh7HK/ which works on an `input` field but not on a `ContentEditable` field, although, selecting all *does* work

This works:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("contentEdit");
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(elem);
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

This doesn't:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("contentEdit");
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(elem, 5) // breaks range Object?
range.setEnd(elem, 8)   // breaks range Object?
range.selectNodeContents(elem);
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

The `.setStart()` and `.setEnd()` should work like that, right?

I've looked at the limited Documentation of `jQuery carrot`, `jQuery selection`, `Rangy` etc., but they all seem to be aimed at *getting* the selection not *setting* it.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. `selectNodeContents(node)` moves the range to encompass the whole content of `node`, so your `setStart()` and `setEnd()` calls are essentially ignored.
2. `setStart(node, offset)` moves the range's start boundary to offset `offset` within `node`. In the case of element, that means placing the boundary after `offset` child nodes of the element. In the case of a text node, which is probably what you want, the range boundary is placed after `offset` characters. Same with `setEnd()`. If you have a single text node within your editable element, you're probably done. Once you start have nested elements, you may want a [more subtle approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16100733/96100) if you want to set the selection relative to your editable element's text content.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/24117242/96100.