# Set the caret at the end of the content in Froala 2

Tags: javascript, froala

I'm using Froala 2 and the documentation doesn't seem to have anything that implies a simple way to set the location of the caret, let alone at the beginning or end. I'm trying to seed the editor instance with a little content in certain cases and when I do using `html.set`, the caret just stays where it is at the beginning and I want to move it to the end. The internet doesn't seem to have anything helpful around this for v2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Froala support provided an answer for me that works:

```
var editor = $('#edit').data('froala.editor');
editor.selection.setAtEnd(editor.$el.get(0));
editor.selection.restore();
```

Comment: This answer is correct, however the thing that tripped me up is the editor has to _already be focused_ for it to work. If you want to force focus on the editor before calling this call `editor.events.focus()`.

Comment: `editor.$el.get(0)` in this context did not always work as expected. What worked better for me was `editor.selection.endElement()`.

Comment: My answer applied to some version of Froala 2. Maybe you're using a newer version where my answer doesn't work as well anymore?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Froala 2 doesn't provide any API to do this, but you can use native JavaScript [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection).

This code should do the job:

```
// Selects the contenteditable element. You may have to change the selector.
var element = document.querySelector("#froala-editor .fr-element");
// Selects the last and the deepest child of the element.
while (element.lastChild) {
  element = element.lastChild;
}

// Gets length of the element's content.
var textLength = element.textContent.length;

var range = document.createRange();
var selection = window.getSelection();

// Sets selection position to the end of the element.
range.setStart(element, textLength);
range.setEnd(element, textLength);
// Removes other selection ranges.
selection.removeAllRanges();
// Adds the range to the selection.
selection.addRange(range);
```

See also:

- [How to set caret(cursor) position in contenteditable element (div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div)
- [Set caret position at a specific position in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115860/set-caret-position-at-a-specific-position-in-contenteditable-div)