# Create button onclick function to act as arrow keys do

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, onclick

I have this Java script function that acts as a back space.  This works fine but now I want to create a button that goes back, and one that goes forward without deleting the text ( like the behavior of your arrow keys ) .  Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

```js
 function setBack() {
     document.getElementById('user').value = 
     document.getElementById('user').value.substring(0, 
     document.getElementById('user').value.length - 1);
 }
```

```html
 <input id="user" type="text">
 <button type="button" onclick="setBack();">backspace</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="">back</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="">forward</button>
```

No jQuery please Native Javascript only.

Comment: this might help: http://www.codescratcher.com/javascript/get-or-set-cursor-position-in-a-textarea/

Comment: Have you checked @DavidShack 's answer? The jsFiddle works as you asked.

Comment: There was a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115860/set-caret-position-at-a-specific-position-in-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by obtaining the cursor location which is possible with **selectionStart**. Here is the sample code. You can add more features to this as per the requirement.

```
function back(){

                console.log(user.selectionStart-1)
                if(user.selectionStart !== 0 ){
                user.focus();
                user.selectionEnd = user.selectionStart
                user.selectionStart = user.selectionStart-1
                }

            }
function forward(){

                console.log(user.selectionStart)
                user.focus()
                user.selectionEnd = user.selectionStart+1
                user.selectionStart = user.selectionStart+1

            }
```

Comment: This works great except it highlights the char when it moves back but it doesnt do that with forward button.  If it didnt highlight the text it would be fine.

Comment: if you add the -1 to user.selectionEnd = user.selectionStart instead of ser.selectionStart = user.selectionStart it solves the hi-light problem.

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try:

```js
       
            let input = document.getElementById('Test');
            input.focus();
              
            let index = 0;

            document.getElementById('Prev').addEventListener('click', function(){
                
                index -= 1;
                
                if(index <= 0) {
                    index = input.value.length;
                }

                input.focus();
                input.selectionEnd = index;
                input.selectionStart = index;
            });


            document.getElementById('Next').addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log(index);
                
                index += 1;
                
                if(index > input.value.length) {
                    index = 0;
                }

                input.focus();
                input.selectionEnd = index;
                input.selectionStart = index;
            });
```

```html
        <input id="Test" type="text" value="helloooo">
        <button id="Prev">Prev</button>
        <button id="Next">Next</button>
```

Comment: It is appreciated to post answer in snippets rather than `jsFiddle` as OP understands it better and it is much appreciated by the community.

Comment: Like @manikant gautam answer this is close to what I want except the fact that when you type then press back works fine but if i type then hit back again it jumps to the previous point where you began instead of moving back one space.

Comment: in other words if i type, click back, type again, then click back again it doesn't move one space back but before the new text.

Comment: @MunimMunna Thank you. I've updated my post to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: @Jonny You can add an keyup event listener to update the cursor position after adding/removing characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can store `caret` position inside `var say caretPosition` . And pass `caret position` after back and forward. Just `increment pos` on forward and `decrement pos` on back. here is how i have tried.

```js
var caretPosition = 0;
function updateLength(){
  caretPosition =  document.getElementById('user').value.length 
}
function setBack(e) {
     var str= document.getElementById('user').value;
     var position =document.getElementById('user').selectionStart;
     caretPosition = position-1;
     document.getElementById('user').value = 
     str.substring(0,position - 1) + str.substring(position, str.length)
     resetCaretPosition('user',caretPosition);
    
 }
 function back(){
   caretPosition =(caretPosition>1)?caretPosition-1:caretPosition ;
   resetCaretPosition('user',caretPosition);
}
 
 function forward(){
   caretPosition =caretPosition+1 ;
   resetCaretPosition('user',caretPosition);
 }
 function resetCaretPosition(elemId, caretPos){
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
    if(elem != null) {
        if(elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if(elem.selectionStart) {
                elem.focus();
                elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
            }
            else
                elem.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="user" oninput="updateLength()"  type="text">
 <button type="button" onclick="setBack(event);">backspace</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="back()">back</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="forward()">forward</button>
```

Comment: in other words if i type, click back, type again, then click back again it doesn't move one space back but before the new text.  This has the same bug as @David Shacks answer