# Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, range

I have this problem with Chrome and Safari (works in Mozilla and IE + Edge).
I want to store the caret position and selection using `range=sel.getRangeAt(0);`

However, I get the following error in Chrome:
`Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index.`

How can I fix this in another way than the following: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935320/uncaught-indexsizeerror-failed-to-execute-getrangeat-on-selection-0-is-not).

This is my **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/311ts2g1/1/)**

The reason why I can't use this method is because I display a `hidden` `div`, and insert text into an `<input type="text">` field, I then insert that into a `contenteditable` `div`. Selecting this input field makes me save a new selection, and messes up the insert.

Here are some images to display the problem:

**Part 1: The `contenteditable` div fields**
[image: Part 1, the table]
**Part 2: The hidden div that is displayed, and typing, changing the carter position**
[image: Part 2, Typing in the URL that gets added.]
**Part 3: On insert, console error in Chrome and Safari**
[image: Part 3, The Error Code]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you be able to provide jsfiddle example with this issue?

Comment: See provided fix of similar problem. Exactly the same issue. Only problem is that he solves the problem for a <option> menu. While I change my carter position in a type="text".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so i`ve found a mistake in your code, and it was pretty simple, though hard to find :)

**Issue:**

Line 46/72: bE1.focus() does not work therefore object Selection.range does not exist.
I`ve did simple check by calling console.log(document.activeElement) to check which element is active in page, and that was wrong element.

**Solution:**

Changed bE1.focus() -->  div_new_1.focus()

**Working example:** [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/311ts2g1/3/)

**Functions i`ve changed:**

```
function lrestoreRangePosition1() {
  closePopupLink1();
  div_new_1.focus();
  var sel = window.getSelection(),
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  var x, C, sC = bE1,
    eC = bE1;

  C = rp.sC;
  x = C.length;
  while (x--) sC = sC.childNodes[C[x]];
  C = rp.eC;
  x = C.length;
  while (x--) eC = eC.childNodes[C[x]];

  range.setStart(sC, rp.sO);
  range.setEnd(eC, rp.eO);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range)
}

function lrestoreRangePositionInsert1() {
  var newText1 = document.getElementById('url_title1').value;
  var newText2 = document.getElementById('url_content1').value;

  var pasteText = "<a href='" + newText2 + "'>" + newText1 + "</a>";
  closePopupLink1();

  div_new_1.focus();
  console.log(document.activeElement)
  var sel = window.getSelection(),
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  var x, C, sC = bE1,
    eC = bE1;

  C = rp.sC;
  x = C.length;
  while (x--) sC = sC.childNodes[C[x]];
  C = rp.eC;
  x = C.length;
  while (x--) eC = eC.childNodes[C[x]];

  range.setStart(sC, rp.sO);
  range.setEnd(eC, rp.eO);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);

  pasteHtmlAtCaret(pasteText);
}
```

Let me know if that helps:)

Comment: I got Uncaught TypeError: div_new_wrap.focus is not a function... how come?