# Chrome getRangeAt issue when programmatically changing the innerHTML of a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

my html is as follows:

```
<button onclick="testfunction()">test</button>
<div id="divT" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById("divT").innerHTML = "bla bla bla";

function testfunction() {
    try {
        if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
            var s = window.getSelection();
            var range = s.getRangeAt(0);
            range.collapse(true);
        }

    }
    catch(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

in Google chrome, when i try to change programmatically like in the above code, the content of that div and then run the `testfunction`, I get a:
`failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index`

However if i manually change the content, no such problem. Firefox works ok.

Is this a bug? Thank you in advance for your help

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/borw7n0h/
just click the test button

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935320/uncaught-indexsizeerror-failed-to-execute-getrangeat-on-selection-0-is-not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

`document.getElementById("divT").focus()`