# How to get cursor HTML offset in contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, html, range, rangy

I'd like to get the number of characters between the start of a container and the cursor (including tags characters).

**Example :**

```
<div id="contentEditor" contenteditable="true">
    <p>This| is an<br></p><p>example.<br></p> <!-- The | represents the cursor and is not a character in the HTML -->
</div>
```

Here the cursor (`|`) should have an offset of 7, not 4.

This is because I want to add text at the cursor index.
So far I'm using [this answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container) function called `getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin`. But this doesn't count tags length.

The following code should add a new paragraph at the cursor index, but I don't get the correct index:

```
var index = getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(document.getElementById("contentEditor-Content"));
var content = document.getElementById("contentEditor").html();
document.getElementById("contentEditor").innerHTML = content.substring(0, index) + "<br></p><p>" + content.substring(index, content.length);
```

`getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin` code I'm using : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TjXEG/900/)

Comment: You should call it "cursor", "caret" usually refers to the `^` character.

Comment: Oh, ok my bad. I'm changing it right away ! ;)