# How can I change textArea text color dynamically?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm creating SQL query editor.My idea is there is a `textarea` in which user insert query like `select * from tbl` and then I get text from `textarea` and then put in `sqlcommand` and execute query and show result in gridview.But Problem is how can I change keyword color like when user enter `INSERT` or `SELECT` command then automatically it change color `blue` like in SQL query editor and all other keywords like `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and so on.How can I change color runtime in textarea.

Comment: You may better off with using a library like [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/). What's it for?

Comment: Can you provide me example or tutorial .I don't know how to use this library

Comment: I'm working in ASP.NET C#.Visual studio 2010

Comment: @Ashley did you click Praveen's link? It goes straight to the documentation.

Comment: A naive approach would contain a background worker which scans the content of the textarea for keywords over and over again, and reacts in a certain way...

Comment: I want this in `textarea` because i get this text and put in `sqlcommand`

Comment: @Rory I check link but using this i can't get text from this technique.Can any one provide me example how can i use this technique in visual stduio asp.net c#

Comment: @BenWin You right 100%.But How can i do this?

Comment: If I'm understanding you, you're trying to implement syntax highlighting? It's not possible to color portions of the text within a `<textarea>`; you would need to use a contentEditable html block at minimum.

Comment: @DanielBeck Can you provide me links?

Comment: Provide you links to what?

Comment: @DanielBeck which may help me out and resolve my problem.You great.I want this.Highlight keywords

Comment: The links already provided to you by Praveen and Vish should be enough to get you started: either use existing code (such as the one Praveen suggested) or implement your own (per the answers in the question Vish linked to below).

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using css .
Note-Change color to any choice(this one is red):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    input, select, textarea{
    color: #ff0000;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
    color: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <textarea id="textarea" cols="20" name="S1" rows="2"></textarea></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

I thought to try but you can get this is already done :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139076/change-color-of-specific-words-in-textarea
```

Comment: Thanks for help .But You not understand my question well.My question is how to change text color for every keywords at run time.For example if write `SELECT` then it green and other text not green it's normal.ONLY KEYWORDS will be green like `SELECT`,`INSERT`,`DELETE`,`UPDATE` etc.I'm not asking for whole text color red.

Comment: oh..ok.will make some changes.

Comment: Yes.Make some changes please do it

Comment: Does that link helped? if not it will take time to write alternative solution(i.e . basically what ben said-a backgroundworker process)

Comment: Thanks Vish.I try your provided link solution.When i execute its running but problem is color not changing

Comment: `<div id="editor" contentEditable="true"></div>` here is error. contentEditable is not valid attribute

Comment: its part of html 5.I am not sure what you are using

Comment: Can you help me on teamviwer please.here is my email `ashley168878@gmail.com `

Answer (score -1):

You said it's a c#/javascript problem so i assume it's a web site on the client side. If so i don't think you are able to change color of each individual word in an textarea but you should use some 3 party plugins to get an "improved" textarea or use other tags to achieve this functionality

Comment: I try this link solution `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139076/change-color-of-specific-words-in-textarea' but When i execute its running but problem is color not changing

Comment: It's not changing because you are matching value form the text area against those if statements. If you write only one word, let's say SELECT it will color it but after that everything else you type even space wont match anything in the if statements because the value won't match. You need some kind of plugin or nest html tags inside each other to accomplish what you need

Comment: I just noticed that the answer for that question is what you need more or less. You can copy it and adjust as you see fit

Comment: Can u help me here is my e-Mail `ashley168878@gmail.com `

Comment: Help with what? You just need to copy&pate that code into your own, i just tested it and it works fine. Can you elaborate where the problem is? Here you can see that it is working http://jsbin.com/xikikamufa/3/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I copy paste but not working.I'm using first solution.It's running but color not changing

Comment: did you click on the link i gave you? you can see it's working

Comment: here working fine i know but not working in visual studio 2010.

Comment: I can see only the 2 picture. Have you included the css file as well in your application?

Comment: Yes i have css code in aspx file.Here you can see http://i68.tinypic.com/140cc1t.png

Comment: what do you get why you run the app? can you send a picture of that

Comment: I'm getting div with background color black when i write `SELECT` and press space then color not changing of `SELECT`

Comment: Does it color the syntax when you only type select? Maybe the jquery is not loading check if there are any error in the chrome console (or some other browser you are using)

Comment: No it's not color the syntax when i write `SELECT` and how can i check chrome console?

Comment: ctrl+shift+i or right click with mouse and inspect element