# Javascript change font color when using textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to add different colors to the objects below... the way I'm doing is not working when I output to a textarea.

```
//Print out InputTextToSave 10
                document.getElementById('inputTextToSave10').innerHTML= 
                "Name" + "\n" + studentname.fontcolor("red").bold()
                + "Number " + studentnumber.fontcolor("blue").bold();

<textarea id="inputTextToSave10" style="width: 1300px; height: 857px; 
background-color: #333333; font-family: Arial; font-size: small; font-
weight: normal; color: #FFFFFF;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Alexa, you can not use different colors in the same textarea.

Comment: What are `studentname` and `studentnumber` ? 
You say it's not working. Do you get an error?

Comment: Similar post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139076/change-color-of-specific-words-in-textarea

Comment: You will need to switch from textarea to a contenteditable="true" div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color of specific words in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139076/change-color-of-specific-words-in-textarea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.textarea_type_div{
  width: 1300px; 
  height: 857px; 
  background-color: #333333;
  font-family: Arial; font-size: small; 
  font-weight: normal; 
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.textarea_type_div .studentname{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:red;
}

.textarea_type_div .studentnumber{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea_type_div" contenteditable="true">
  <span class="studentname">Student Name</span>
  <span class="studentnumber">Student Number</span>
</div>
```

Instead of `textarea` you can make a `div` and give that `div` a property called `contenteditable="true"` and in that you can write and change the text color as per your need.

You can refer this [link for more help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139076/change-color-of-specific-words-in-textarea)

Also, You can use texteditor plugin such as [The Yahoo RTE](https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/simple_adv_editor.html), [the FCKEditor](https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/FCKEditor/) and [the Lightweight RTE](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lwrte/).

Hope this helps.