# Setting a different color only for words which came out of dropdown in textarea editor(angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, textarea

**What I did:**

I have a **dropdown**. I also have a **textarea**. I enter text in **textarea** and I also choose words from the **dropdown** and add it to the **textarea**. I have done this part.

**Problem:**

Now I wanna differentiate the words which came from the **dropdown**. So I wanna show those particular words alone in red color. Any word entered through **dropdown** or any word entered by hand which is same as any one of the  **dropdown** value should be shown in **red** color. This is what I am trying to do . I have searched stackoverflow but I could find any solutions. Kindly help if you guys know

**Code:**

**My HTML:**

```
<textarea #text [(ngModel)]='textValue' rows="10" cols="70">
</textarea>
<div>
  <mat-form-field class="input-style">
    <label>Dropdown</label>

    <mat-select (change)="changeValue($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let li of list4" [value]="li">
        {{li}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**My TS:**

```
  changeValue(ev) {
        this.textValue += ` ${ev.value}`;
      }
```

I have attached my stackblitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-tfw6de?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update 04-04-2021*** please take a look to Owen Kevin's answer in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66899473/highlight-specific-words-in-textarea-angular-8)  because my code don't take account the "scroll"

the only way to "highlight" text inside a textarea is to have two layers, one with a text area and another one with a div with `[innerHtml]`

the problem with a textarea is that you need use the same font-family than the div

from [this codePen](https://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/gaLEMR) the .html like

```
<div class="container" [style.width]="text.getBoundingClientRect().width+'px'"
                      [style.height]="text.getBoundingClientRect().height+'px'">
  <div class="backdrop">
    <div class="highlights" [innerHtml]="textFormatted"></div>
  </div>
  <textarea #text [ngModel]='textValue' (ngModelChange)="change($event)" rows="10" cols="40">
</textarea>
</div>
```

A function "formatted"

```
  formatted(message:string)
  {
    return message.replace(/\n/g, "<br />").replace(this.regExpr,"<mark>$&</mark>")
  }
```

replace the message with the "mark" in the words selecteds

```
  regExpr=new RegExp(this.list4.map(x=>'('+x+')').join('|'),"g");
```

Remember call to this.formatted each time you change the textarea

```
  changeValue(ev) {
    this.textValue += ` ${ev.value}`;
    this.textFormatted=this.formatted(this.textValue);
  }
  change(message:string)
  {
    this.textValue = message;
    this.textFormatted=this.formatted(this.textValue);

  }
```

And, behare! the .css to change the mark should be in the styles.css

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-jeawj8?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.ts)

**Update** if we want to change into italic is that we need made transparent the text-area color and colored the "hightlight". This make "loose" the cursor.

```
.highlights {
    ...
    color: #444;
}
textarea {
  ....
  color: transparent;
}
```

We can use [-webkit-text-fill-color](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/) but it's not a standards css (works on FireFox, Chrome and Edge)

```
@supports (-webkit-text-stroke: 1px black) {
  textarea {
    color:#444;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px transparent;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

The [modiffied stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-xnhqud?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.css)

Comment: Thanks for the try but its very buggy and not working in many scenarios

Comment: Instead of coloring is there anyway to change it into italic?

Comment: the problem to change into italic is that we need made transparent the text-area color and colored the "hightlight". This make "loose" the cursor, see the updated answer. Sorry I don't know why it's the reason "not work in many scenarios"

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the colours of words in a `<textarea>`, but you can use the contenteditable attribute to make a `<div>`, `<span>`, or `<p>` look like a .

See how to change colors of editable div here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37160584/14820590

and for you to code jquery style in your angular typescript, import this:

`import $ from 'jquery';`