# Set specific character bold in input inTypescript

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript, input, angular-material

I have an Input field. On a click function I want some characters in that input to get bold.

[[image]

Expected output on some click event :
**Fred's** Fishing Lodge rbs.software.testing@gmail.com

Comment: you need a testarea to bold a text. take a look this SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66899473/highlight-specific-words-in-textarea-angular-8

Comment: No i need to bold some character based on some condition in Input type