# Highlight text/number/data inside input field using keydown in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have an input field in which I write some text/numbers/etc . I get the data in this input field after I press Tab key. I want to add a button next to the input field which gets clicked after I press Tab key. Also I wish the data/text/etc inside the input field gets highlighted(blue selection) when I press Tab key.

Here's the code so far.

> HTML file

```
<input (keydown.Tab)="ABC($event)">
```

> TS file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab',
  templateUrl: './tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab.component.css']
})
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ABC(event:any){
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: are you looking for some like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66899473/highlight-specific-words-in-textarea-angular-8)?

Comment: Actually I am looking for a way that highlights the entire text in the input field when I press tab key .

Comment: some like :`<input [class.hightlight]="hightlight" (focus)="hightlight=false" (blur)="hightlight=true">`?

Comment: I'll try this out , I just now tried it in javascript and it worked for "Enter" key but I want it to work when I press 'Tab'. I'll post another question maybe that helps me clear up my concept. Also thank you for the help :D.