# Dynamically Highlight Words Based on its Dictionary value

Tags: javascript, html

I was able to get some help from a previous post where I wanted to highlight words dynamically as a user entered text.

The previous condition would highlight a word if it began with "t", now I want to update this condition to highlight any words that meet a condition based on dictionary values (I call JavaScript's built in object a dictionary).

For example, if I have a dictionary `dict = {"test": 5.0, "check": 4.0, "stop": -1.5, "fair": 2.0}` how would I have the script highlight words whose value was greater than 2.0?

Failed code:

```js
dict = {"test": 5.0, "check": 4.0, "stop": -1.5, "fair": 2.0}

function highlighter(ev) {
  // Get current cursor position
  const currpos = getSelectionDirection(ev) !== 'forward' ? getSelectionStart(ev) : getSelectionEnd(ev);
  // Change innerHTML to innerText, you
  // dont need to parse HTML code here
  var content = ev.innerText;
  var tokens = content.split(" ");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    if (dict[tokens[i][0]] > 2.0) {
      tokens[i] = "<mark style='background-color:red; color:white;'>" + tokens[i] + "</mark>";
    } 
  }
  ev.innerHTML = tokens.join(" ");
  // Set cursor on its proper position
  setSelectionRange(ev, currpos, currpos);
}
```

```css
/* NOT REQUIRED AT ALL, JUST TO MAKE INTERACTION MORE PLEASANT */
.container {
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onkeypress=highlighter(this) contenteditable>
</div>

<script>
// Usage:
// var x = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]');
// var caretPosition = getSelectionDirection(x) !== 'forward' ? getSelectionStart(x) : getSelectionEnd(x);
// setSelectionRange(x, caretPosition + 1, caretPosition + 1);
// var value = getValue(x);

// it will not work with "<img /><img />" and, perhaps, in many other cases.

  function isAfter(container, offset, node) {
    var c = node;
    while (c.parentNode != container) {
      c = c.parentNode;
    }
    var i = offset;
    while (c != null && i > 0) {
      c = c.previousSibling;
      i -= 1;
    }
    return i > 0;
  }
  function compareCaretPositons(node1, offset1, node2, offset2) {
    if (node1 === node2) {
      return offset1 - offset2;
    }
    var c = node1.compareDocumentPosition(node2);
    if ((c & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY) !== 0) {
      return isAfter(node1, offset1, node2) ? +1 : -1;
    } else if ((c & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS) !== 0) {
      return isAfter(node2, offset2, node1) ? -1 : +1;
    } else if ((c & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING) !== 0) {
      return -1;
    } else if ((c & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING) !== 0) {
      return +1;
    }
  }

  function stringifyElementStart(node, isLineStart) {
    if (node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'br') {
      if (true) {
        return '\n';
      }
    }
    if (node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div') { // Is a block-level element?
      if (!isLineStart) { //TODO: Is not at start of a line?
        return '\n';
      }
    }
    return '';
  }
  function* positions(node, isLineStart = true) {
    console.assert(node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE);
    var child = node.firstChild;
    var offset = 0;
    yield {node: node, offset: offset, text: stringifyElementStart(node, isLineStart)};
    while (child != null) {
      if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        yield {node: child, offset: 0/0, text: child.data};
        isLineStart = false;
      } else {
        isLineStart = yield* positions(child, isLineStart);
      }
      child = child.nextSibling;
      offset += 1;
      yield {node: node, offset: offset, text: ''};
    }
    return isLineStart;
  }
  function getCaretPosition(contenteditable, textPosition) {
    var textOffset = 0;
    var lastNode = null;
    var lastOffset = 0;
    for (var p of positions(contenteditable)) {
      if (p.text.length > textPosition - textOffset) {
        return {node: p.node, offset: p.node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? textPosition - textOffset : p.offset};
      }
      textOffset += p.text.length;
      lastNode = p.node;
      lastOffset = p.node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? p.text.length : p.offset;
    }
    return {node: lastNode, offset: lastOffset};
  }
  function getTextOffset(contenteditable, selectionNode, selectionOffset) {
    var textOffset = 0;
    for (var p of positions(contenteditable)) {
      if (selectionNode.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE && selectionNode === p.node && selectionOffset === p.offset) {
        return textOffset;
      }
      if (selectionNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && selectionNode === p.node) {
        return textOffset + selectionOffset;
      }
      textOffset += p.text.length;
    }
    return compareCaretPositons(selectionNode, selectionOffset, contenteditable, 0) < 0 ? 0 : textOffset;
  }
  function getValue(contenteditable) {
    var value = '';
    for (var p of positions(contenteditable)) {
      value += p.text;
    }
    return value;
  }
  function setSelectionRange(contenteditable, start, end) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var s = getCaretPosition(contenteditable, start);
    var e = getCaretPosition(contenteditable, end);
    selection.setBaseAndExtent(s.node, s.offset, e.node, e.offset);
  }
  //TODO: Ctrl+A - rangeCount is 2
  function getSelectionDirection(contenteditable) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var c = compareCaretPositons(selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorOffset, selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset);
    return c < 0 ? 'forward' : 'none';
  }
  function getSelectionStart(contenteditable) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var c = compareCaretPositons(selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorOffset, selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset);
    return c < 0 ? getTextOffset(contenteditable, selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorOffset) : getTextOffset(contenteditable, selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset);
  }
  function getSelectionEnd(contenteditable) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var c = compareCaretPositons(selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorOffset, selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset);
    return c < 0 ? getTextOffset(contenteditable, selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset) : getTextOffset(contenteditable, selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorOffset);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Refer to this answer here [How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript) you can also check this [https://markjs.io/](https://markjs.io/)

Comment: I have seen this before, but this works on button click (which could work just as well) but I'm looking to have this happen as the user types.

Comment: Also check here [Highlight text inside of a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142527/highlight-text-inside-of-a-textarea)

Comment: I'm implementing your first suggestion now, though I will leave question open to see if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code I used this Cool js lib [jQuery highlightTextarea](http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/) and as per your requirements, I loop through your `dict` object and push only those words that have a value greater than 2.0.

```js
dict = {"test": 5.0, "check": 4.0, "stop": -1.5, "fair": 2.0}

var words = [];

Object.keys(dict).forEach(function(key) { 
  if( dict[key] > 2 ){
    words.push(key);
  }
});

$('textarea').highlightTextarea({
  words: words,
  caseSensitive: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/dist/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/dist/jquery-highlighttextarea/jquery.highlighttextarea.min.css">
<script src="http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/dist/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/dist/jquery-highlighttextarea/jquery.highlighttextarea.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="demo-case" cols="50" rows="3" style="background: none;" spellcheck="true">This is a test you can check or stop it will be fair enough.</textarea>
```

More options here http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/#options

Other example here http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/examples.html

Comment: I like this, but the issue here is that if I type in a word that is similar to a word in the ```words``` array, then I the highlighting still happens. For example, when I type the word ```testing```, I can see the root word highlighted (which I don't want)

Comment: I think you can give it try to this one [Change color of specific words in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139076/change-color-of-specific-words-in-textarea/)