# how to detect all hashtags in textarea angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sass

I have a text area

```
    <textarea  class="text-area" (focus)="focusIn()" (focusout)="focusout($event)" formControlName="text" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

I want to make some function that will detect when a user wrote # add some color for that word for example

```
hello #world
```

Here world will have some background

I have not an idea how to realize the function

Comment: This will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139076/change-color-of-specific-words-in-textarea/37160584 . You can't change color only for some in a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to capture all text which will match a pattern which define the structure of you tags

```js
let pattern = /(#\w+)/gm;
let chaine = "hello #world #another tags";

let matches = [...chaine.match(pattern)];

console.log(matches);
```

As tags start with a `#` character you can use this pattern `/(#\w+)/gm` with will capture all tags in a given string.

You can learn more about [String.proptotype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) at this link