# How to change color of certain words in <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an interactive programming website where users can type 3 commands: `turn right`, `turn left` and `forward n`. `<textarea>` to type commands:

`<textarea name="codeEditor" id="codeEditor" ></textarea>`

[image: How it looks]

Text is white. If user types any of the commands then text should turn orange. How to accomplish this with `<textarea>`?

Comment: I am bit out of the loop with JS and family, but as far as I remebr textarea didn't allow to change per word style. Check this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37160584/1139052). with Regex then probably you have more control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach uses an `<input>` element for entry and a list to display the command history. There is a transition to highlight the previous command and an error message to help the user.

```js
const entry = document.getElementById("entry");
const error = document.getElementById("error");
const history = document.getElementById("history");
let last = document.getElementById("last");
let prev;
entry.addEventListener("change", evt => {
  const valid = evt.target.checkValidity()
  error.classList.toggle("hidden", valid);
  if (valid) {
    prev = document.createElement("li");
    prev.textContent = entry.value;
    history.insertBefore(prev, last);
    last = prev;
    entry.value = '';
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  background-color: black;
}

#history {
  list-style: none;
  height: 9rem;
  color: white;
}

#history li {
  color: white;
  transition: color 2s;
}

#history li:first-child {
  color: #0ff;
}

#entry {
  background-color: black;
  color: #2f2;
  border: 1px solid white;
  outline: none;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.error {
  font-size: .5rem;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="entry" placeholder="command" pattern="(turn (left|right)|forward \d+)" required>
<span id="error" class="error hidden">'turn left', 'turn right' or 'forward #'</span>
<ul id="history">
  <li id="last"></li>
</ul>
```