# How can I get correct position of caret in a text with newlines in conteneditable div(IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="contenteditablediv" contenteditable="true"><div>
```

I enter this  text into  contenteditable div.

```
Text1


Text2
```

I have contenteditable div here. And there are 2 newline between **Text1** and **Text2**. I can not get correct position of caret when there are empty newlines, because I guess  `<br>` are not taken into consideration by this code.

This codes doesn't help!

```
function getCaretPosition(element) {
    var caretOffset = 0;
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
        preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
        caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    return caretOffset;
}   

var position = getCaretPosition(document.getElementById('contenteditablediv'));
```

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container/4812022#4812022

Comment: @Teuta Koraqi  this doesn't help either...