# How to get the index of the caret position element in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, parent-child, contenteditable, caret

Lets say I have a contenteditable div which also has some element in it

```
<div id="text" contenteditable="true"><b>abc</b><nav>def</nav><span>ghi</span></div>
```

Now if the cursor or caret position is within the `span` element, how do I get the index of the `span` element as a child node to its parent element `div`. So I can have this result

```
divNode = document.querySelector('div');
spanIndex = //get the index of span element which will be = 2
caretEle = divNode.childNodes[spanIndex];
```

**NOTE:** I am not looking for the caret position, I want to get the child index of the caret position element to its parent element. ie I want to get the child index of the `<span>` element to the `<div id="text" contenteditable="true">`

For example:

```
node = document.getElementById('text');
node.childNodes[0] == <b>
node.childNodes[1] == <nav>
node.childNodes[2] == <span>
```

Comment: You may look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091730/get-and-set-cursor-position-with-contenteditable-div ------

Comment: Its not possibly a duplicate. I have tried that solution yet not good.

Comment: How is it *not good?*

Comment: Is this one *good*? http://stackoverflow.com/q/40747657/2813224 or how about this one is it *good* http://stackoverflow.com/q/40747657/2813224 ? You can't modify what you already have?