# Count cursor position with tags included in range

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I am trying to find position of cursor in **contentEditable** div which has HTML tags inside it.

Example of div would be:

```
<div id='editor'>
   <h2>some</h2> text <span>goes here</span>
</div>
```

So if cursor is on letter "T" in 'text' word i want to get position that includes:

```
"<h2>some</h2> t"
```

not just

```
"some "
```

I have found solution that doesn't count tags in position: [Get a range's start and end offset's relative to its parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container/4812022#4812022)

This works fine but i need to count tags as well in final range.

Comment: What is your use case for such position? If you are trying to edit the html code to insert some value at cursor position, you can just modify the text node given by Range object and read innerHTML of the contentEditable div to get the value you need

Comment: @AvcS I need to alter content of #editor, specifically to add string on cursor position, example if cursor is on letter "T", altered #editor would be:
<div id='editor'>
   <h2>some</h2> t New Text ext <span>goes here</span>
</div>

Comment: Then you can do it exactly like how I said above, trying to get the cursor position in HTML is hectic and might get wrong, because depending the editor and styles you use attributes will change

Comment: @Avc if i get window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) and get Range object, won't that return only 1 node? Like 1 node inside #editor? Also this will return range based on node that is holding text, not on #editor (i might be wrong, it would be nice if you could give me some example), thanks!

Comment: I can give you an example, gimme 5 mins

Answer (score 0):

Range object gives a range indicating DOM elements currently selected, it gives you information regarding in which element, at which position selection started  and in which element, at which position selection ended.

```
function replaceSelectionWith(value) {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    const {
        startContainer,
        startOffset,
        endContainer,
        endOffset
    } = range;

    if(startContainer === endContainer) {
        const container = startContainer;
        // nodeType === 3 means text node, can also check same using nodeName === '#text'
        if (container.nodeType === 3) {
            container.nodeValue = container.nodeValue.slice(0, startOffset) + value + container.nodeValue.slice(endOffset);
        }
    }
}
// Once you change the DOM, you can just get your HTML value from #editor.innerHTML
```

This is a simplest usecase, which is your scenario right now. But it is possible that `startContainer` and `endContainer` are different nodes or they can be DOM elements instead of being simple text nodes. This example is just to set you in the right direction.

You can refer to following documentation to understand how they actually work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range

**EDIT: Working solution for the case asked in question**

```
function insertTextAndGetHTML(value) {
    replaceSelectionWith(value);
    return document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: i understand range start and end container/offset but i this will give me current node, for example range will be counted from <span> instead of <div id='editor'>

Comment: Yes but in this way i will lose parent node, do you understand my issue?
Example: <div>foo <span>bar</span></div> if user click on "bar" and inserts text result will be <span>bar next text</span> instead of <div>foo <span>bar new text</span></div>

Comment: range object from your example will be some node inside #editor, not #editor itself thats why i will get only that node set if i do document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML = replaceSelectionWith("new text"). Please share some example since i tried it with your example and insert is working but replaceSelectionWith function is not getting good return value

Comment: The purpose of the function above is just to insert text at the location of cursor, not to return any node or value and it is just an example not complete solution.

Comment: ok, but this doesn't solve anything for me. thank you for trying