# get and set cursor position in content editable div

Tags: javascript, cursor, contenteditable

in a content editable div, i wish get and set cursor position but but without taking into account the child elements (, , etc for example).

for get, i find this solution : [Get a range's start and end offset's relative to its parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container/4812022#4812022)

but for set, i don't know.

please, can u help me.

thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rangy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rangy) to define it yourself, just like this:

```
var selector = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]');

var setCaretIndex = function (index) {
    var charIndex = 0, stop = {};

    var traverseNodes = function (node) {
        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
            if (index >= charIndex && index <= nextCharIndex) {
                rangy.getSelection().collapse(node, index - charIndex);
                throw stop;
            }
            charIndex = nextCharIndex;
        }

        // Count an empty element as a single character. The list below may not be exhaustive.
        else if (node.nodeType === 1 && /^(input|br|img|col|area|link|meta|link|param|base)$/i.test(node.nodeName)) {
            charIndex += 1;
        } else {
            var child = node.firstChild;
            while (child) {
                traverseNodes(child);
                child = child.nextSibling;
            }
        }
    };

    try {
        traverseNodes(selector);
    } catch (ex) {
        if (ex !== stop) throw ex;
    }
};
```

To use this function, you need to focus the editor first:

```
selector.focus();
```

Then giving an index to set cursor position:

```
setCaretIndex(3);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntnguyen/gmhuo70e/6/)