# How do I calculate the x,y coordinates of my cursor while editing a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `contenteditable` div and I need to show a custom element at the cursor position whenever a user types a certain character.

To do this, I need to know where the cursor (not the mouse - the vertical line that letters come out of) is located whenever this happens. How can I do this?

Comment: Related: [get and set cursor position in content editable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894560/get-and-set-cursor-position-in-content-editable-div)

Comment: @Tân how would I display a div at an *index* (as opposed to coordinates)?

Comment: You can use it within keyboard events: *input, keypress, keydown....*. You can generate your custom div element and append it based on the cursor position

Comment: @Tân again... how can we extrapolate x/y coordinates for a div (that needs to be positioned with x/y coordinates) from cursor position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you mean correctly, you may want to insert some div element into `[contenteditable]` element based on cursor position.

If true, you can try this way:

```js
function append(node) {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  range.deleteContents();
  range.insertNode(node);
}

add.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var node = document.createElement('div');
  node.innerText = 'foo';
  node.className = 'test';
  
  append(node);
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.test {
  color: #f00;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>Hello world!</div>
<button type="button" id="add">Append text</button>
```

In this example, you can click on the editor to set cursor position, then clicking on the button to append new div tag.

---

You can also use this way to append some div tag via `input` or `keypress` or `keydown`... events by detecting character, such as: *@ #*