# How to get cursor position in text within contenteditable excluding tags?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, cursor-position

Assume I have this html code within contenteditable div:

```
<div contenteditable>This is an example of some <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i> and normal text.</div>
```

We see this text within browser (with stripped tags):

```
This is an example of some bold and italic normal text.
```

Assume I put a cursor within word "italic".

How to get cursor position not counting tags?

**Upd.**

I want to do some kind of mapping between text and inline tags. For example, I want to get something like this:

```
[
    {
        content: 'This is an example of some ', 
        start: 0,
        end: 27,
    },
    {
        content: 'bold',
        type: 'bold',
        start: 28,
        end: 31, 
    },
    {
        content: ' and',    
        start: 32,
        end: 35,    
    },
    {
        content: 'italic',
        type: 'italic',
        start: 36,
        end: 41, 
    },
    {
        content: ' and normal text.',       
        start: 42,
        end: 58, 
    },
]
```

Comment: May you elaborate more on what you are trying to accomplish here? What do you mean by "not counting tags"? I am assuming you could just get the cursor position then evaluate the event.target.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @akaizn, position of cursor within string with tags and without tags will be different. I want to know position only for text with stripped tags.

Comment: @V.Sambor , I know how to get cursor position within contenteditable with html tags according this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container/4812022#4812022 (or of another answers of Tim Down). I want to do some kind of mapping between text, and inline tags. Wait a minute, I will do an update to my question.

Comment: @V.Sambor, I have made an update to my question.

Comment: Ok I see. Do you really have to display the text rendered as html? because if it can be plain text, then your problem is easily solved...

Comment: @V.Sambor, it should be wysiwyg editor, that is why I want to use contenteditable div instead of textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to work with : [`window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)

Result of window.getSelection() :

[image: Result of window.getSelection()]